# Twitter Bootstrap. Как изменить расстояние между top и блоками?

Tags: фреймворк, bootstrap

Например возьмем:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
 <div class="span4">
   <h1>Title</h1>
 </div>
```

Расстояние от top к блоку 75 пкс.
то есть `top:75px;`
Как изменить расстояние?
Извините за это "глупый" вопрос. С фреймворками мало знаком, только начал изучать. Многое не понятно.
Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 1):

top:75px - отступ в 75 пикселей с верха, вы можете увеличить цифру и увеличится расстояние, вы предпочли создать здесь аккаунт, оставить вопрос, вместо того что бы попробовать самому? : )

Comment: ))) да уж .. ты хотя бы раз видел этот фреймворк?
он на LESS.
там расстоянию наверняка должно соответствовать какая-то переменная.
я не говорю что я нашел top:75px
я не знаю где и какую переменную нужно изменить.
т.е. мне нужно найти этот top )